# Accepting Partial Answers

Tags: discussion

**What is the best response to an answer that only answers part of a question, but answers that part excellently?**

Take a look at [this question](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/948/user-preferences-via-soql-or-api) of mine.  At of 8/29/2012, there is an accurate & complete answer to one of the points, but nothing on the second.  What do we want to establish as a practice in these situations?

1. I don't accept an answer, because there's nothing complete
2. I accept the best answer, but then others may stop trying to answer the other part of the question.
3. I edit the question to match the answer, then re-post the other piece as a new question
4. Others ideas?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think that just like Daniel pointed in his comment. It's better to split the answer.

You can still, edit your question, leave the part where the answer is complete. And write a new question with the missing part.